# If $A$ has column $1$ + column $2$ $=$ column $3$, show that $A$ is not invertible:

Tags: linear-algebra

(a) Find a nonzero solution $x$ to $Ax = 0$. The matrix is $3$ by $3$.

**My solution:**

$$\begin{bmatrix} { a }_{ 1 } & { b }_{ 1 } & { a }_{ 1 }+{ b }_{ 1 } \\ { a }_{ 2 } & b_{ 2 } & { a }_{ 2 }+{ b }_{ 2 } \\ { a }_{ 3 } & b_{ 3 } & { a }_{ 3 }+{ b }_{ 3 } \end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Therefore, the vector $x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$ solves $Ax =0$

(b) Elimination keeps column $1$ $+$ column $2$ $=$ column $3$. Explain why there is no third pivot.

Now, I have no idea how to approach the second part of this question. I would appreciate a hint that would allow for me to figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a third pivot, then elementary row operations can reduce the third row to $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: Ok, I think your hint helped me see the picture better. So, after elimination columns $1$ and $2$ both end in zeros. Then, Column $1$ + Column $2$ $=$ Column $3$ must mean that column $3$ ends in a zero, and thus there is no third pivot. Is that right?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer That's exactly right.